# Rewrite Query String in Between 2 Paths

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, query-string

I'm new to .htaccess so hopefully someone can help me out.

I'm trying to redirect these:

```
clan.php/tagID=clanstag
clanRatings.php/tagID=clanstag
```

to this:

```
/clan/clanstag
/clan/clanstag/ratings
```

So far I have the clan.php redirecting correctly but I can't get the clanRatings.php to redirect correctly. It keeps thinking the Clans tag is clantag/ratings.

This is the code I'm using now:

```
# Rewrite clan.php
   RewriteEngine On
#url redirection from old url to the new one
#redirect /clan.php?tagID=TAG to /clan/TAG
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /clan.php\?tagID=([^\s]+) [NC]
   RewriteRule ^.+$ /clan/%1? [L,R]
#url rewiring from new url to the old one
# rewrite /clan/TAG to /clan.php?tagID=TAG
   RewriteRule ^clan/(.*)$ clan.php?tagID=$1 [L]
```

and

```
# Rewrite clanRatings.php
   RewriteEngine On
#url redirection from old url to the new one
#redirect /clanRatings.php?tagID=TAG to /clan/TAG/ratings
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /clanRatings.php\?tagID=([^\s]+) [NC]
   RewriteRule ^.+$ /clan/%1?/ratings [L,R]
#url rewiring from new url to the old one
# rewrite /clan/TAG/ratings to /clanRatings.php?tagID=TAG
   RewriteRule ^clan/(.*)$/ratings clanRatings.php?tagID=$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Instead of `RewriteRule ^clan/(.*)$/ratings clanRatings.php?tagID=$1 [L]` try `RewriteRule ^clan/([^/]+)/ratings clanRatings.php?tagID=$1 [L]`

Comment: @JM-AGMS It still gives the same error where it thinks the clan tag contains /ratings.